# Listview not updating but in logs adapter is changing data

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have created a generic ArrayList and generic array adapter for the custom view that contains a search view and listview. for this listview, I have created generic ArrayList and generic arrayadapter that I will be using just for updating the data and setting it up on listview.i am dynamically updating the ArrayAdapter via casting. but when I update it via notifydatasetchanged it does not update. In logs, I am getting the desired list of states and districts, but it's not updating on the listview.

```
public class activitySignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

     //  Tag for logs...
     private final String TAG = getClass().getName();

     //  Opens up Popup list for Selection...
     private AppCompatTextView StateInput;
     private AppCompatTextView DistrictInput;

     //  Popup view for Selection...
     private AlertDialog builder;

     //  For Custom Views...
     private ListView listView;
     private SearchView searchView;

     //  Created Different Types Method and Adapters for different kinds of classes...
     private static ArrayList < ? > GeneralList;
     private static ArrayAdapter < ? > GeneralAdapter;

     //  This class will be used for storing View ID of the view, by clicking on we opened up the
     //  custom alert dialog. This class will be useful in Updating the Clicked UI.
     private LastViewClicked lastViewClicked;

     //  For Storing Current values of selected items, will be helpful in dynamic function calls...
     private static State Currentstate;
     private static District Currentdistrict;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

      initView();
     }

     private void initView() {
      SignUpBar = findViewById(R.id.SignUpBar);
      setSupportActionBar(SignUpBar);

      StateInput = findViewById(R.id.stateInput);
      DistrictInput = findViewById(R.id.districtInput);

      //  Inside context i am passing the context of the view according to switchview...
      //  intentRelatedTasks are for Passing intents...
      //  For showing error there's show Error...
      builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activitySignUp.this).create();
      View custom_view = LayoutInflater.from(activitySignUp.this).inflate(R.layout.popup_view, null);

      searchView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.search_bar);
      searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

      listView = custom_view.findViewById(R.id.list_all);
      listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

      builder.setView(custom_view);

      //  Initializing ArrayLists and Setting them up on Adapters...
      GeneralList = new ArrayList();
      GeneralAdapter = new ArrayAdapter < > (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, GeneralList);

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
      searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

      //  TextView on Click Listeners...
      StateInput.setOnClickListener(this);
      DistrictInput.setOnClickListener(this);

      //  Initializing class...
      lastViewClicked = new LastViewClicked();

     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
      switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.stateInput:
        //  Storing the ID of the Last Clicked Item, which will be used in updating the UI on
        //  ListItem Click...
        lastViewClicked.setView(StateInput);
        getStates();
        break;
       case R.id.districtInput:
        //  Storing the ID of the Last Clicked Item, which will be used in updating the UI on
        //  ListItem Click...
        lastViewClicked.setView(DistrictInput);
        if (GeneralList.isEmpty()) {
         Alerts.showToast(this, "Select State First...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        } else {
         if (Currentstate != null) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "get Districts...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          getDistrictsByStateId(Currentstate.getId());
         }
        }
        break;
      }
     }

     private void getStates() {
      Api.getStates(new Callback < BasicResponse > () {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call < BasicResponse > call, Response < BasicResponse > response) {
        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.isSuccessful()) {
         BasicResponse basicResponse = response.body();
         String res = basicResponse.getResponse();
         Type listType = new TypeToken < ArrayList < State >> () {}.getType();
         ShowList(GeneralList, GsonUtils.fromGson(res, listType), GeneralAdapter);
         builder.show();
        }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call < BasicResponse > call, Throwable t) {
        Alerts.showToast(getApplication(), getResources().getString(R.string.NetworkError), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        Log.i(TAG, t.getMessage());
       }
      });
     }

     private void getDistrictsByStateId(String stateId) {
      Api.getDistrictsByStateId(stateId, new Callback < BasicResponse > () {
       @Override
       public void onResponse(Call < BasicResponse > call, Response < BasicResponse > response) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GetDistrictsByStateId");
        Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful()));
        Log.i(TAG, GsonUtils.toGson(response.body()));

        if (response.isSuccessful() && response.isSuccessful()) {
         BasicResponse basicResponse = response.body();
         String res = basicResponse.getResponse();
         Type listType = new TypeToken < ArrayList < District >> () {}.getType();
         ShowList(GeneralList, GsonUtils.fromGson(res, listType), GeneralAdapter);
         builder.show();
        }
       }

       @Override
       public void onFailure(Call < BasicResponse > call, Throwable t) {
        Log.i(TAG, t.getMessage());
       }
      });
     }

     private void ShowList(ArrayList arrayList, ArrayList new_list, ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter) {
      arrayList.clear();
      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      if (!new_list.isEmpty() && new_list != null) {
       arrayList.addAll(new_list);
      }

      arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     }

     //  Listview function that performs Action on OnItemClick...
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView << ? > adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
      switch (lastViewClicked.getView().getId()) {
       case R.id.stateInput:
        Currentstate = (State) GeneralAdapter.getItem(position);
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: StateName" + Currentstate.getStateName());
        break;
       case R.id.districtInput:
      //  I am getting Error here stating that Adapter of State type cannot be cast to District Type.... 
        // I am updating the adapter inside getStates Class and getDistrictbyState method but it's not updating...
        Currentdistrict = (District) GeneralAdapter.getItem(position);
        break;
      }
      searchView.setQuery("", false);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
      GeneralAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
      return true;
     }

     @Override
     public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {

     }
    }
```